# GCD of numbers confusion

Tags: c++, greatest-common-divisor

I was looking for simple code for calculating gcd of 2 numbers and came across this code which works

```
ll gcd(ll a, ll b){
  return b ? gcd(b,a%b):a;
}
```

I was trying to make this code work

```
ll gcd(ll a, ll b){
  return a ? gcd(a%b,b):b;
}
```

No matter what I do, I am not able to get the second code block to work. My reason is simple, no matter how I start, I should be able to get GCD. Can someone please help me understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: Make sure you understand how the original function works before you start fiddling with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap `a` and `b`, you must do two things:

- Replacing every `a` with a `b` and every `b` with an `a`
- Changing the order of the arguments passed to each recursive call to `gcd`.

You have done it partially. What you need to do is:

```
return a ? gcd(b%a, a):b;
```

What you have generates infinite recursion. For example, if you call `gcd (12, 8)` with your modified function, this is what you get at each iteration:

```
a = 12, b = 8
a = 4, b = 8
a = 4, b = 8
a = 4, b = 8
...
```